# Remove spaces from array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string which contains numbers separated by commas. It may or may not have a space in between the numbers and a comma in the end. I want to convert it into an array, that I can do using following code:

```
$string = '1, 2,3,';
$array = explode(',', $string);
```

However the additional irregular spaces gets in the array values and the last comma causes an empty index (see image below).

[image]

How can I remove that so that I get only clean values without spaces and last empty index in the array?

Comment: `$array = array_map('trim', $array);$array = array_filter($array);`

Comment: @b0s3, i don't know why you used array_filter here, as array_map is doing the job.

Comment: @Insomnia - if you read the topic he needs to remove empty values aswell...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply use `array_map`, `array_filter` and `explode` like as

```
$string = '1, 2,3,';
print_r(array_map('trim',array_filter(explode(',',$string))));
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

**Explanation:**

Firstly I've split string into an array using `explode` function of PHP

```
print_r(explode(',',$string));
```

which results into

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] =>  2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 
)
```

So we need to remove those null values using `array_filter` like as

```
print_r(array_filter(explode(',',$string)));
```

which results into

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] =>  2
    [2] => 3
)
```

Now the final part need to remove that `(extra space)` from the values using `array_map` along with `trim`

```
print_r(array_map('trim',array_filter(explode(',',$string))));
```

SO finally we have achieved the part what we're seeking for i.e.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/448964)

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I needed to remove spaces from an array.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution would be to use `str_replace` on the original string and also remove the last comma if it exists with a `rtrim` so you dont get an empty occurance at the end of the array.

```
$string = '1, 2,3,';
$string = rtrim($string, ',');
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
$array = explode(',', $string);
print_r($array);
```

RESULT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First perform following on the string -

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
```

Then use explode.

Comment: For whitespaces better use trim().

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '1, 2,3,';
$array = explode(',', $string);
$array = array_filter(array_map('trim', $array));

print_r($array);
```

[array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) is a very useful function that allows you to apply a method to every element in an array, in this case `trim`.

[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) will then handle the empty final element for you.

Answer (score -1):

This will trim each value and remove empty ones in one operation

```
$array = array_filter( array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $string ) ) );
```